# java null /empty-list return vs throw exception in code rethinking best practices in rest world

Tags: java, design-patterns, junit, nullpointerexception

rethinking on design-patterns with null /empty handling scenarios

a function like below

```
  function(customerid){
      customer=findcustomerbyId(customerid)-->findcustomer
      list<Transactions> accounts=getNewTransactions(customer)-->findtransactions
      foreach{if(transaction.isGasTransaction()){send(event)..if()sendevent()}}-->send events
    }
```

now the question is whenever we are expecting a return value from a function ,should it be a null value ? or if the db can not find a value should it throw exception.

throwing null value forces you to write code to handle null-values/emptylists. which will increase if-else blocks and your junit cases also increase (directly proportional). throwing exceptions will force you to a different programming style and again you need some test cases expecting the exceptions.

like spring-jdbc template queryForObject throws exception if there is no value in db.(expected-1 but got 0)

what is the right direction here. more exceptions ?  or use Optionsl<>java-8 like other null alternatives or use nulls?

we can balance these styles in different scenarios :)

so for a rest-api project i am thinking throwing exceptions will be good ,if you have a global-excpetion-handler(like controller advice) reason,you can handle exceptions in your code and not worry of method-stack to handle null checks/empty checks as exceptions are caught at advice level and is propagated accordingly.

*** this is to think in a direction rather than discussing which is best*****

Comment: Yours seems to be a style or best practices question.  Design patterns are an altogether different and more specific thing.

Comment: yes,i agree with style vs best practices, i did choose  exception style in this project but what about new ppl joining ,is it a best practice so that ppl understand that easily.
the try catch is not needed in my scenario as i explained i have a global exception handler to return the customized e.message as a response of the service .for debugging later

Comment: It seems to me that you want to use exceptions for flow control/signaling. But, imho, exceptions should be used as what they are: exceptions, indicating that something went wrong. If the absence of data during your test means that something is indeed wrong, then throwing an exception seems OK to me. But generally you should revisit your design and think about what methods should return in what scenarios and especially what the value null means to you. Null-objects are OK in some cases too. Think about what pollutes your code less. Also using a global exception handler looks like a design smell

Comment: This is serious ground work and needs some thought :P at my workplace we struggle with that as well, because people habe different opinions about it. If you program in a team: speak to them and argue about the pros and cons of every approach. Make a decision and stick to it! If you think using exceptions everywhere is fine, that's OK as long as you don't change your mind midway and start using null-objects.

Comment: i see the point, and this was a long debate in my team.I tend towards exceptions as this scenario of mine makes no sense.with null data as the next steps in the logic will not be executed if  there is a null.(90% of time ppl do not expect null values ex:- getCustomer with id, verify credit card pin etc).Any null check is good to have but not necessary as this is only to increase junit coverage and service call won't come to this level if some values are null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself "What do I want to happen when someone tries to access an entry that doesn't exist?"

**If you want to display a message to the user**, you could throw a handled `Exception` to inform the next level up that a problem has occured, allowing you to display some kind of error message in the `catch` block.

**If you want nothing to happen**, use a null object so your thread doesn't blow up. The user will not be informed as to why nothing happened, which is considered to be bad practice.

**If the lack of an entry prevents the program from functioning properly**, a `Runtime` exception would be used. `NullPointerException` isn't detailed. An NPE could occur from forgetting to initialize a variable (usually caught at compile time in modern languages) as opposed to accessing an element in some kinda of data structure that isn't there (usually causing an `NoSuchElementException` in modern languahes), so it's best to wrap the NPE in another exception which includes more info about the problem.

Comment: What about returning an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)?

Comment: yes, thts why i have a customized exception handler tht catches these and transofrms to something meaningfull for the user. null is a bad :)
and optional doesnot simply solve because then u run into other side of null-handling scenarios.But yes optional is still better than null

Comment: @dnault `Optional` would be useful if he wanted to create the missing data if unavailable. Displaying an error message to the user should not be the responisiblity of the data handler - it should be the responisibility of either the object in charge of the data handler (which it may be propegated even further up the chain), or an error handler. In my opinion, `Optional` harms modularity. The best thing to do in this case would be to throw an exception of some kind to let the higher tier know that there was a problem, so it can either add data, display data or send it to some error handler.

Comment: yes,thank you that helps a lot.I am doing the same thing. Throwing a runtime exception,because anyway it is a rest service and ppl calling it don't care except ,if there is a problem in the input either way the case ends,me going through logs and see what happened.Most no of bugs should be resolved during dev(integration/unit tests)
I do not want to  handle n-null checks to get 1 result .(handling if/else blocks just increases the tests which look ugly) :)

Answer (score 0):

If the database cannot find a value - is this a disaster or a normal situation? Consider these two cases:

```
public void createUser(String userName){
boolean thisUsernameIsUsed = checkIfUsernameAlreadyExistsSQLRequest(userName);
    if(!thisUsernameIsUsed){
        //create a new user
    }
}
```

and

```
public String whoMessedUpTheDatabase(database database){
    return database.getLastEditedBySQLRequest();
}
```

In the first case it is OK to not have the username in a database. So, use null. In the second case we expect to have get the name of the last editing person, so having null is really an exception.

Comment: boolean flag will return true/false so no null.
and also create user sort of operation always throws exception if it cant
but i get the point ,u say incase of null if you want some thing else to happen return null other wise throw exception. But i feel some how null is a mistake that some-how ended in programming languages

Comment: Sure, boolean is a true/false, not exception, not null. My point is - if blank responce is a drama - use exception. If it is ok - return null.